# Adding new div with Id inside existing div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to add a div within an existing div via JS. I am using the code below, but it's not working.

HTML:

```
<div id="hashtag-content-footer">
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$("#hashtag-content-footer").append("<div id='newid'></div>");
</script>
```

Please help.

Comment: so what is the problem,,,, any error in your console

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9LaLerbL/1/ ?

Comment: I am not getting error. But new div is not added to existing div.

Comment: @ANI How do you know it's not added?

Comment: try this $( document ).ready(function() {
$("#hashtag-content-footer").append("<div id='newid'></div>");
});

Comment: see the above demo... it is working perfectly... try to add your script in a dom ready handler if needed - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9LaLerbL/2/

Comment: I checked using inspect element. Its not showing new div. I am not getting where am going wrong.

Comment: @ANI Can you make a demo with jsFiddle?

Comment: as per your code , you have not included jquery file. either include CDN or download .js file of jquery and include it.

Comment: @ANI try to log $("#hashtag-content-footer") in console and see what happening and also to append it from console itself.

Answer (score 1):

Try writing in `$(document).ready` event:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#hashtag-content-footer").append("<div id='newid'></div>");
    });
</script>
```

`$(document).ready` event is fired when the whole of `DOM` is loaded. So your code will execute when the whole of `DOM` is ready to be manipulated.

Comment: not really required if the script is after the `hashtag-content-footer` element - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9LaLerbL/4/

Comment: yes but we don't know the full structure of the doc. just given some idea.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you're confused between JavaScript and jQuery.

jQuery is a JS plugin which help you manipulate your DOM elements. The code that you're trying to execute using jQuery and you need to add it to your page.

You can get it from here: [jQuery Download](http://code.jquery.com/)

If this is not the issue, the code that you've posted seems to be missing a closing tag for your `div`.

It should be:

```
<div id="hashtag-content-footer"></div>
```

Comment: If it's not loaded then the poster won't be able to evaluate `$` without getting an error.

Answer (score 0):

Problems with your code:

1. No content given to either `div` so it won't be visible but it will there.

So give content or height or border to the divs. place your script in `$(document).ready()`

The html becomes:

```
<div id="hashtag-content-footer">Test</div>
```

The JS becomes:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#hashtag-content-footer").append("<div id='newid'>ABC</div>");
});
```

See the fiddle: "http://jsfiddle.net/bzb4um1b/"

Comment: Missing a `div` tag is not a problem. Browser will automatically close it.

Comment: It could be achieved using different ways. I just told one of the approaches to make it visible. Yours is also correct.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 Surely it would close :) but it is safer to do it yourself.

Comment: @NikhilBatra Indeed, just pointing out that is unlikely the core problem.

Answer (score 0):

It helps to create the new div first. `var newDiv = document.createElement ("DIV");`
Then append that element to your existing div

```
existingDiv.appendChild(newDiv);
```

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 thats the problem

Comment: @­Ittociwam - Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

try this in your script.

```
$( document ).ready(function() { 
    $("#hashtag-content-footer").append("<div id='newid'></div>"); 
});
```

remember to set some borders and width other div won't visible.

Exp:

$( document ).ready will make sure the dom is ready manipulations. go through about it [here](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

Answer (score 0):

as per your code , you have not included jquery file.
either include CDN or download .js file of jquery and include it.

Comment: This should go in comment rather than an answer.

Answer (score 0):

have you use this beacuse your code is working properly

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope This Code will Help you. It will add `<DIV>` with a **Unique ID**

**Html Code**

```
<div id="divContainer">
</div>

<button type="button" id="btnClick">Click Me! </button>
```

**JS Code**

```
var counter = 0;
$("#btnClick").on("click",function(){
    counter = counter + 1;
    $("#divContainer").append("<div id='newid"+counter+"'></div>");
});
```

and Here working Fiddle.
[JSFiddle for adding Dynamically](http://jsfiddle.net/Hardy_411/ndwqkko3/)